# I would like to deploy an API using pytorch. Is there any good deployment location?

Tags: opencv, pytorch, fastapi

I made an API using pytorch, fastAPI and opencv, but when I deploy it to heroku, it's too big to deploy. So, I'm thinking of deploying on another site. Is there any good site? Hopefully you can use it for free without having to think about the size of pytorch, fastAPI and opencv.

Comment: You got multiple tips in your last posts about using the `cpu` versions of the libraries, which should be small enough to be deployable through regular slugs. Did you try the suggestions as given there?

Comment: I tried it, but I posted this because it will exceed 500MB if I include opencv, numpy, torch models, etc.